# Proof verification: If $x_ny_n$ is convergent, then $x_n,y_n$ are also convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I proved this my trying to prove the contrapositive: if one of $x_n$ or $y_n$ is divergent, then $x_ny_n$must be also divergent. But we can have $x_n$ = n and $y_n=1/n$, where $x_ny_n=1$. Thus, a contradiction. Therefore, $x_ny_n$ being convergent does not imply $x_n,y_n$ to be both convergent.

Comment: You can also take $x_n = (-1)^n$ and $y_n = (-1)^{n+1}$ to get an even stronger conclusion.

Comment: How about $x_n=n$ and $y_n=0$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I see there are many counterexamples